# Categorising Date columns into Seasons

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

Problem is to categorize the dates columns from dataframe named a into seasons as mentioned below:

June, July and August: Summer.
December, January and February: Winter.

Dataframe as mentioned below:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'11-12-2018':[20,38,44,51],
                  '21-01-2018':[33,49,51,68],
                  '11-02-2018':[57,66,71,80],
                  '03-08-2018':[33,47,51,50],
                  '11-06-2018':[44,60,71,80],
                  '23-07-2018':[12,23,45,55]},index=list(range(1,5)))
```

My attempt:

```
a.rename(columns={'11-12-2018':'Winter','21-01-2018':'Winter'})
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Not sure multiple columns with the same name makes too much sense

Comment: If you're struggling with getting the season for a date, [check this](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/find-the-season-for-a-date-6fda7a8230bb). You can split your season into 2 parts: before and after newyear to eliminate problems

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @[*Gareth Webber*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199721/gareth-webber), it does not make much sense to have duplicated columns names.

Maybe, you need a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) ?

```
d_map = {"December": "Winter", "January": "Winter", "February": "Winter",
         "June": "Summer", "July": "Summer", "August": "Summer"}

seasons = [d_map[m] for m in pd.to_datetime(a.columns, dayfirst=True).month_name()]
​
a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([seasons, a.columns])
```

Output :

```
print(a)
​
      Winter                           Summer                      
  11-12-2018 21-01-2018 11-02-2018 03-08-2018 11-06-2018 23-07-2018
1         20         33         57         33         44         12
2         38         49         66         47         60         23
3         44         51         71         51         71         45
4         51         68         80         50         80         55
```

Comment: **NB**: To retrieve the data of a *specific season*, use `a["Winter"], a["Summer"], ...`.